# How to use SUM() and merge tables into one table with SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

I've tried with **`UNION`** but it only returned the result with **`P4`**. What I had now is **4 separate `SELECT` queries** and they has the same data with **`GROUP BY` for `P3` and `P4`**. Hence, I would like to merge these data into **ONE** temporary table.

How to:

1. Merge these tables into one table first
2. then SUM() columns by each Plant

as my image below.

[image: Merge1]

**SQL:**

```
DECLARE @Plants TABLE
(
    PlantName nvarchar(30),
    MaterialTotalPrice DECIMAL(18,2),
    SumLaborCost DECIMAL(18,2),
    FinalCost DECIMAL(18,2)
)

DECLARE @PlantName nvarchar(30)
DECLARE @MaterialTotalPrice DECIMAL(18,2)
DECLARE @SumLaborCost DECIMAL(18,2)
DECLARE @FinalCost DECIMAL(18,2)

SELECT
    @PlantName = GetTotalPrice.[PlantName]
    ,@MaterialTotalPrice = SUM(GetTotalPrice.[MaterialTotalPrice])
    ,@SumLaborCost = SUM(GetTotalPrice.[SumLaborCost])
    ,@FinalCost = SUM(GetTotalPrice.[FinalCost])
FROM
(

    SELECT
        TotalPriceMP4.[PlantName]
        ,SUM(TotalPriceMP4.[MaterialTotalPrice]) AS 'MaterialTotalPrice'
        ,SUM(TotalPriceMP4.[SumLaborCost]) AS 'SumLaborCost'
        ,SUM(TotalPriceMP4.[FinalCost]) AS 'FinalCost'
    FROM Invoice1 AS TotalPriceMP4
    GROUP BY TotalPriceMP4.[PlantName]
    UNION
    SELECT
        TotalPriceMP4.[PlantName]
        ,SUM(TotalPriceMP4.[MaterialTotalPrice]) AS 'MaterialTotalPrice'
        ,SUM(TotalPriceMP4.[SumLaborCost]) AS 'SumLaborCost'
        ,SUM(TotalPriceMP4.[FinalCost]) AS 'FinalCost'
    FROM Invoice2 AS TotalPriceMP4
    GROUP BY TotalPriceMP4.[PlantName]
    UNION
    SELECT
        TotalPriceMP3.[PlantName]
        ,SUM(TotalPriceMP3.[MaterialTotalPrice]) AS 'MaterialTotalPrice'
        ,SUM(TotalPriceMP3.[SumLaborCost]) AS 'SumLaborCost'
        ,SUM(TotalPriceMP3.[FinalCost]) AS 'FinalCost'
    FROM Invoice3 AS TotalPriceMP3
    GROUP BY TotalPriceMP3.[PlantName]
    UNION
    SELECT
        TotalPriceMP3.[PlantName]
        ,SUM(TotalPriceMP3.[MaterialTotalPrice]) AS 'MaterialTotalPrice'
        ,SUM(TotalPriceMP3.[SumLaborCost]) AS 'SumLaborCost'
        ,SUM(TotalPriceMP3.[FinalCost]) AS 'FinalCost'
    FROM Invoice4 AS TotalPriceMP3
    GROUP BY TotalPriceMP3.[PlantName]

) AS GetTotalPrice
GROUP BY GetTotalPrice.[PlantName]
INSERT INTO @Plants(PlantName, 
                    MaterialTotalPrice, 
                    SumLaborCost, 
                    FinalCost) 
 VALUES (@PlantName, 
         ISNULL(@MaterialTotalPrice,0), 
         ISNULL(@SumLaborCost,0), 
         ISNULL(@FinalCost,0))
SELECT * FROM @Plants
```

Comment: you should not be using UNION, use UNION ALL, you could get incorrect results if there are duplicate rows that union (when used alone) will remove before the final calculations. UNION ALL actually does less work too (bit faster).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really is important to know when NOT to use union by itself.

```
declare @t table ( planname varchar(50), finalcost float)
declare @t1 table ( planname varchar(50), finalcost float)
declare @t2 table ( planname varchar(50), finalcost float)
declare @t3 table ( planname varchar(50), finalcost float)

insert into @t values ( 'P3', 100.00)
insert into @t1 values ( 'P3', 100.00)
insert into @t2 values ( 'P3', 100.00)
insert into @t3 values ( 'P3', 100.00)

select planname, SUM(finalcost)  from 
(
select planname, SUM(finalcost) finalcost from @t group by planname
union ALL
select planname, SUM(finalcost) from @t1 group by planname
union ALL
select planname, SUM(finalcost) from @t2 group by planname
union ALL
select planname, SUM(finalcost) from @t3 group by planname
) 
a group by planname
;
```

**result = 400**

if you use union by itself the result would be 100.00

Answer (score 1):

You are near to your work, you just again group by on topmost select

Merge :- union is the good thing for multiple entry in one roof.

Why you use temp table ? if without temp table you get the desired thing.

```
declare @t table ( planname varchar(50), finalcost float)
declare @t1 table ( planname varchar(50), finalcost float)
declare @t2 table ( planname varchar(50), finalcost float)
declare @t3 table ( planname varchar(50), finalcost float)

insert into @t values ( 'P3', 851872.651973)
insert into @t1 values ( 'P3', 1219860.129705)
insert into @t2 values ( 'P4', 7569113.509084)
insert into @t3 values ( 'P4', 24701896.712498)

select planname, SUM(finalcost)  from 
(
select planname, SUM(finalcost) finalcost from @t group by planname
union
select planname, SUM(finalcost) from @t1 group by planname
union
select planname, SUM(finalcost) from @t2 group by planname
union
select planname, SUM(finalcost) from @t3 group by planname
) 
a group by planname
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, because there are not only 4 `SELECT` queries for `P3` and `P4`. What if when there are more than 20 queries? So that do I have to declare 20 tables?

Comment: fine,so now what challenge you face? you can use temp table as declare keyword for optimize issue or you can use CTE for this also. Create a temp table take memory ,such thing will avoid by above this suggestion or use when too much necessary

Comment: I would like to add more `SELECT` queries as much as I can and then I just use `GROUP BY` with `PlantName`. According to your answer and my problem now. Which one takes more memory than the other one? The `UNION` is optional, can be changed or removed. Actually, the best solution is also to solve the optimize issue.

Comment: please take note of UNION ALL (which will do less work too) union by itself can give you incorrect results